# Chaining output of an async method as input of another async method c#

Tags: c#, async-await, call, chain

I have the following code section in which SavePersonAsync method were calling 3 external methods and could anyone tell me the implementation of async/await methods were implemented correctly. Does any of the call chains in which async/await was not implemented correctly?

```
    public PersonService(IPersonDbService personDbService,
        IPersonEntityToPersonModelMapper personEntityToPersonModelMapper,
        IPersonModelToPersonEntityMapper personModelToPersonEntityMapper)
    {
        _personDbService = personDbService;
        _personEntityToPersonModelMapper = personEntityToPersonModelMapper;
        _personModelToPersonEntityMapper = personModelToPersonEntityMapper;
    }


    public async Task<IEnumerable<PersonModel>> SavePersonAsync(IEnumerable<PersonModel> personsModel)
    {
        var personsEntity = await _personModelToPersonEntityMapper.MapPersonModelToPersonEntityAsync(personsModel);

       var savedPersons = await _personDbService.SavePersonAsync(personsEntity.First()); // Currently only alow one person at a time, later it will allow to save a collection of persons

        return await _personEntityToPersonModelMapper.MapPersonEntityToPersonModelyAsync(new List<PersonEntity>
        {
            savedPersons
        });
    }
}

public class PersonEntityToPersonModelMapper : IPersonEntityToPersonModelMapper
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<PersonModel>> MapPersonEntityToPersonModelyAsync(
        IEnumerable<PersonEntity> personsEntity)
    {
        if (personsEntity.NullOrEmpty())
            return await Task.FromResult(Enumerable.Empty<PersonModel>());

        return await Task.FromResult(personsEntity.Select(personEntity => new PersonModel
        {
            FirstName = personEntity.FirstName,
            LastName = personEntity.LastName              
        }));
    }
}

public class PersonModelToPersonEntityMapper : IPersonModelToPersonEntityMapper
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<PersonEntity>> MapPersonModelToPersonEntityAsync(IEnumerable<PersonModel> personsModel)
    {
        if (personsModel.NullOrEmpty())
            return await Task.FromResult(Enumerable.Empty<PersonEntity>());

        return await Task.FromResult(personsModel.Select(personModel => new PersonEntity
        {                
            FirstName = personModel.FirstName,
            LastName = personModel.LastName               
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why methods `MapPersonModelToPersonEntityAsync` and `MapPersonEntityToPersonModelyAsync` need to be `async` all they are doing is performing a Linq query?

Comment: Those methods were using by other sections of the programs and needed async functionality.

Comment: @TheBeginer you mean that interfaces have different async implementation somewhere else and you have to follow the async signature?

Comment: @cassandrad That's true, the existing implementation of these two interfaces are async (IPersonModelToPersonEntityMapper and IPersonEntityToPersonModelMapper). and I don't want to change it as this has been used by other part of a large application. Let me know if there was any implementation pitfalls? If so how could it can be avoid or improved.

Comment: @TheBeginer, I don't see any, except for lack of `ConfigureAwait(false)` as I don't know how this class will be consumed.

Comment: @cassandrad; this how its been called now; from a web api controller:            
 public async Task<IActionResult> SavePersonAsync(IEnumerable<PersonModel> personsModel)
{

 return Ok(await _personService.SavePersonAsync(personsModels););

}. So you were saying call like this _personService.SavePersonAsync(personsModels).ConfigureAwait(false);

Answer (score -2):

From the definition of async await when you have written await the flow will start sequential, As you need the output to be used in the next statement then there is not much use of async await in your case

To breief about how it works
Suppose you have to method call which can work async in that can your code would be like:

Var a = GetMethodA();

Var b = GetMethodB();

await a;

await b;

In this case your method will work asynchronous